# Access-Control-Allow-Origin that must work for localhost and another domain

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I have put this in my `.htaccess` file, but it only works on localhost:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(localhost|mydomain.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

I have both on my localhost and on server mod_headers enabled.

I get the following error:

> Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, is the response by ajax

Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP response to see what is being returned in that case?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. They are red, so probably it's a 500 error code. Chrome console says no data availablle from response

Comment: Ah yes, that would be a problem. You could try routing through Charles Proxy to see the actual HTTP response.